# Search data by date from a database table using PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, date, pdo

I have a table where a date field (datetime type). Stored data like **2015-12-09 11:33:44** .I have datepicker input field to search data which generated date like **2015-12-09**.So how can i search data using the given date.Assume that i have many data with same date but different time.Is this possible to get all matched data with a given date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

convert your input date in a date range:

```
$inpute_date = '2015-12-09';
$start_date = $inpute_date . ' 00:00:00';
$end_date = $inpute_date . ' 23:59:59';
```

And in your condition:

```
WHERE your_date_col BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'
```

Comment: Just tested my "solution" (using Date()) and yours and ...dang, MyQL really doesn't optimize `WHERE Date(d)='...'` to use the index on d exactly like it does for `d BETWEEN ... AND ...`. (It does use the index, but without index push down).